# How to show the existence of global minimizer of Lasso type of objective function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, vector-analysis, global-optimization

Suppose the objective function to be minimized is
$$F(\theta) = \|y - X \theta\|_2^2 + \sum_{i=1}^p \lambda_i |\theta_i|$$
where $\theta$ is the independent variable which is feasible in $\mathbb{R}^p$. Other quantities $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $X \in\mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$, individual penalties $\lambda_i \geq 0$ are all fixed. Note that some $\lambda_i$'s might be zero. We focus on
high dimension so $p>n$.

$F(\theta)$ is convex. But how to show that there exists $\widehat{\theta} \in \mathbb{R}^p$ such that for any $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^p$, $F(\theta) \geq F(\widehat{\theta})$?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to the following:

- An extended value function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ is said to be *coercive* if $f(x)\to\infty$ as $\|x\|\to\infty$.
- A classic result in convex analysis states that a proper lower semi-continuous and *coercive* function must be bounded below and have (global) minimizers.

With the above, show that the LASSO objective is coercive by showing the function $\theta\mapsto\|y-X\theta\|^2$ is so. Hint: Expand the square.

Comment: Since $X$ is not of full rank as $p>n$, there exists some $\theta_0 \neq 0$ such that $X \theta_0=0$, so that for any $k > 0$, $X(k \theta_0) = 0$. Then $\|y - X(k\theta_0)\|_2^2 = \|y\|_2^2 < \infty$. However, $\|k \theta_0\|_2 = |k| \|\theta_0\|_2 \to \infty$.

Comment: Is that an evidence that $F$ is not coercive?